# Publishing MVC 6 site with Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6 to IIS

Tags: iis-8, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to publish a site to IIS that I am developing using MVC6 (beta 3) with Visual Studio 2015 (CTP 6). I have publishing set to target the x64 version of KRE. All goes well with the publishing, and no errors are reported, but I cannot get the site to run at all.

The first error is that `project.json` cannot be found, but I fixed that by adding the `value` key to `kre-app-base` in the `web.config` that is added to the `wwwroot` folder, so the content is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="kpm-package-path" value="..\approot\packages" />
    <add key="bootstrapper-version" value="1.0.0-beta3" />
    <add key="runtime-path" value="..\approot\packages" />
    <add key="kre-version" value="1.0.0-beta3" />
    <add key="kre-clr" value="clr" />
    <add key="kre-app-base" value="..\approot\packages\ElectricFreedom.WebUI\1.0.0\root" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I then get another error:

[image: Error 500 message]

In the footer of the error, it states that it’s using `Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS` version "beta2"! Why is it doing that when the project is all set up to use "beta3"?

I have checked the `project.json` for my project, and all the dependencies are listed as "beta3" versions, but the publish is still copying across a lot of "beta2" in addition to "beta3" versions. Looking in the directory for `Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS` for example shows two subdirectories, one for "beta2" and another for "beta3". If I delete the "beta2" directory, then I get another error entirely:

[image: Error 500 after deleting beta2 directory]

As you can see, this error shows that it’s using the "beta3" version of `Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS`, but it’s now complaining about dependency injection instead.

All of this worked fine in Visual Studio 2015 CTP5 with MVC 6 (beta 2). The only bit that I had to do was add the `value` key to `kre-app-base` as for some reason publishing failed to do that. The site also works fine when debugging it in IIS Express, and I get none of the errors that are reported above when doing that.

Are there any config files or settings that could be causing these errors to occur? Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks,

Comment: I tested it and I found that it is working for me in CTP6 just like CTP5. Just make sure that you have pointed wwwroot as your rootdirectory of application.

Comment: It is pointed to the wwwroot. It was working fine when I was using CTP5, but the same project no longer works with CTP6. I can only assume that some settings have changed between versions and it causing my project to fail. The trouble is finding whatever has changed and making sure my project has the new settings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there were some temp files created during the publish process that were not being deleted between versions. They were located at `%temp%\AspNetPublish\[ProjectName]`, and deleting that folder removed the errors I was seeing as it cleared out all the old DLL files that shouldn’t have been published and must have been conflicting with the new versions.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to reproduce it by opening CTP5 project in CTP6. I clearly see the problem in some of the assembly.

I did following thing.

1. In Project.json replace beta2 with beta3 in dependencies.
2. Once you perform step1 it will give you migration related issue and reason behind that is there is some change in namespace and return type of some method in AccountController. If you remove migration directory and AccountController after publish it will sucessfully render home/index.

Comment: Yes, I’d gone through those steps to upgrade the project, and everything was compiling okay. It was also running fine through IIS Express. The trouble was when it came to publishing it there were some files left in the temp directory from beta2 which weren’t getting deleted when republishing. As mentioned in my answer, I solved it by deleting all the temp files.